# What does this default applets do?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

This is output of **gp** tool, when I tell it to list installed applets :

```
gp >> gp -l
AID: A000000151000000 (|....Q...|)
     ISD OP_READY: Security Domain, Card lock, Card terminate, Default selected,
 CVM (PIN) management

AID: A0000001515350 (|....QSP|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     A000000151535041 (|....QSPA|)

gp >>
```

**Q1:** Which one of this AIDs are for an applet, and which one is for a Package? How I can recognize?

**Q2:** How I can find out what APDU-commands this applets support? I searched for the AIDs [here](https://www.eftlab.co.uk/index.php/site-map/knowledge-base/211-emv-aid-rid-pix)(a Complete list of AIDs), but found nothing!

**Q3:** Can we have 2 applets inside a single Package? I mean, when I write a *Hello World* applet and upload it to my card, an Applet AID and a Package AID adds to the *gp -l* outputs. Is there any *.cap* file that add for example 3 applet AID and just 1 Package AID to the card?

Comment: A000000151000000 is the card manager applet. Have a look at global platform specification for its interface...

Comment: @vojta What about the others?

Comment: There can be more than one security domain on your card. A0...1515350 is probably a security domain, too.

Comment: @vojta How can I be sure that it is a security domain or s.th. else? And where can I find the list of commands that it is working with?

Comment: http://www.globalplatform.org/

Comment: @vojta I must be a membee and I must pay for it, right?

Comment: no you dont need to pay for it

Comment: Look for card specification section: http://www.globalplatform.org/specificationscard.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. ExM means "Executable module" which means "package".
2. N/A
3. Yes. Have a look here for example: https://github.com/martinpaljak/AppletPlayground/blob/master/build.xml#L53

You really have to go and read some documentation before asking. This is a *programming* forum.

Comment: Thank you dear Martin. What do you mean by `N/A` in second question's answer? Do you mean Not Available? If so, why?

Comment: And also, what is the _.xml_ file that you put its link here? How can I work with it?